# Where to find the fillPatternId?

Tags: c#, api, view, filter, revit

I am trying to set the cut pattern to solid but I couldn't find the fillPatternId
anywhere. Where can I find the fillPatternId?

```
filterSettings.SetCutFillPatternId(fillPatternId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from another forum.  You need something like this:

```
var col = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

var elems = col.OfClass(typeof(FillPatternElement));

/// some logic to select appropriate fill pattern

filterSettings.SetCutFillPatternId ...
```